# Elastic Logstash script for both insert and update

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Newbie with Elastic Stack

I have an oracle database table where rows gets inserted daily at 12 AM and later on those column values will get updated if there is any change in their values.
I tried with doc_as_upsert but the values aren't updating instead of that new rows getting inserted and creating duplicates of that data
There is no unique id for that table.
Can I use elastic id as reference for updating data.
Can anyone suggest any solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add an example of the bulk query and the data to update. 
To make it work you have to ensure to use update, that the ID is strictly the same. that fields syntax is good, and , "doc_as_upsert" : true is added on the doc. If you have duplicated document, you must have an issue in the way you pass your _id